# Solving dependencies on Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, shared-libraries

I've faced a problem with Jessie dependencies. My program was cross compiled on another machine and compilation was ok. It depends on libcurl.so (libcurl.so.4).

When I run it, it complains on:

```
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-deb0.so.28: undefined symbol: nettle_salsa20_crypt
```

My program does not depend directly on libgnutls nor on libnettle4:

```
# readelf -d modules/modhttp.so | grep "NEEDED"
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]

# ldd modules/modhttp.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ede5000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f21000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4 (0x76ea9000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76dcd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76d52000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76d25000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76be4000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libidn.so.11 (0x76ba2000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librtmp.so.1 (0x76b79000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssh2.so.1 (0x76b57000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x76afd000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x7698f000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x76944000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libkrb5.so.3 (0x76890000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x76852000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcom_err.so.2 (0x7683f000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x76823000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x767ce000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x767a7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x7677f000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x54b77000)
    libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-deb0.so.28 (0x76672000)
    libhogweed.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libhogweed.so.2 (0x76639000)
    libnettle.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.4 (0x765f8000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmp.so.10 (0x76586000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x764e3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x764d0000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x764b7000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x764ab000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 (0x76486000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsasl2.so.2 (0x7645f000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x7641e000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.6 (0x763fe000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x763df000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6 (0x763cf000)
```

If I bring all libraries from the compilation environment with the program (with nettle), it runs perfeclty.

Clearly, the problem is in Jessie dependecies between libgnutls and libnettle. How can I solve it?

Comment: `libcurl` comes in three flavors.  One uses openssl, one uses gnutls, and one uses nss.  The gnutls build requires gnutls which uses nettle.  So, perhaps, the cross-compilation platform had the `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` package installed rather than `libcurl4-openssl-dev`  ... It may also be useful to share a snippet of code in order to better address the question of what the compilation may have required.

Comment: The code is standard usage, nothing special:

`CURL* request = curl_easy_init();`

`curl_easy_setopt(request, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);`
`curl_easy_setopt(request, CURLOPT_URL, req->url.c_str());`
`curl_easy_setopt(request, CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING, 1L);`
`curl_easy_setopt(request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);`
`curl_easy_setopt(request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);`
`req->err = curl_easy_perform(request);`

Comment: in addition the environment during compilation is different:
`arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ldd libcurl.so.4.2.0` shows `libssl.so.1.0.0`

Comment: What platform (GNU/Linux?, Mac?, flavor? distro?) was used for cross-compilation?  ... On the compilation machine what is the output of `curl-config --ssl-backends`

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like it, and solve it (python) but shall work like any:

1 [sysconfig file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html) : crossplatform rules and/or dependences(arm,x64 ...)

2 [retrive information](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/579/os.uname) of specific platform (arm,x64 ...)

3 Install (script or tools)specific libraries or tools etc. (apt-get install ...)

I hope it help you